# Arrow (text mode)

Tags: arrows

Which package to use to get the arrow as in the attached image in the text mode (If not exactly, atleast close to it):

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\textrightarrow`?

Comment: Take a look at `pifont`.

Comment: @ egreg Yes, I tried. But then the arrow head  from `\textrightarrow` is different from what I am looking for.

Comment: If you allow mathmode arrows (wrapped in `$...$`) you would have many more choices. The `\rightarrow` from `MnSymbol` looks pretty close to what you showed.